# How do I solve $ \frac{\partial{C(x,t)}}{\partial{t}} = D\frac{\partial^2C(x,t)}{\partial{x^2}}$?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

How do I solve

$$ \frac{\partial{C(x,t)}}{\partial{t}} = D\frac{\partial^2C(x,t)}{\partial{x^2}}\tag1 $$

for $C(x,t)$, given the initial value:

$$ C(x,0) = 0 \tag2$$

and the boundary conditions:

$$ C(0,t) = C_s\tag3$$

$$ C(x,t)  \rightarrow 0, x \rightarrow \infty\tag4 $$

Many thanks.

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%27Alembert%27s_formula

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $C(x,t)=X(x)T(t)$ ,

Then $X(x)T'(t)=DX''(x)T(t)$

$\dfrac{T'(t)}{DT(t)}=\dfrac{X''(x)}{X(x)}=-s^2$

$\begin{cases}\dfrac{T'(t)}{T(t)}=-Ds^2\\X''(x)+s^2X(x)=0\end{cases}$

$\begin{cases}T(t)=c_3(s)e^{-Dts^2}\\X(x)=\begin{cases}c_1(s)\sin xs+c_2(s)\cos xs&\text{when}~s\neq0\\c_1x+c_2&\text{when}~s=0\end{cases}\end{cases}$

$\therefore C(x,t)=\int_0^\infty C_1(s)e^{-Dts^2}\sin xs~ds+\int_0^\infty C_2(s)e^{-Dts^2}\cos xs~ds$

$C(0,t)=C_s$ :

$\int_0^\infty C_2(s)e^{-Dts^2}~ds=C_s$

$C_2(s)=C_s\delta(s)$

$\therefore C(x,t)=\int_0^\infty C_1(s)e^{-Dts^2}\sin xs~ds+\int_0^\infty C_s\delta(s)e^{-Dts^2}\cos xs~ds=\int_0^\infty C_1(s)e^{-Dts^2}\sin xs~ds+C_s$

$C(x,0)=0$ :

$\int_0^\infty C_1(s)\sin xs~ds+C_s=0$

$\int_0^\infty C_1(s)\sin xs~ds=-C_s$

$C_1(s)=-\dfrac{2C_s}{\pi s}$

$\therefore C(x,t)=-\int_0^\infty\dfrac{2C_s}{\pi s}e^{-Dts^2}\sin xs~ds+C_s=C_s\text{erfc}\bigg(\dfrac{x}{2\sqrt{Dt}}\biggr)$

Luckily it satisfies $C(\infty,t)=0$

$\therefore C(x,t)=C_s\text{erfc}\biggl(\dfrac{x}{2\sqrt{Dt}}\biggr)$